# Select the most common value of a column based on matched pairs from two columns using `ddply`

Tags: r, plyr, aggregation, pairwise

I'm trying to use `ddply` (a `plyr` function) to sort and identify the most frequent interaction type between any unique pairs of user from a social media data of the following form

```
from <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D')
to <- c('B', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C')
interaction_type <- c('like', 'comment', 'share', 'like', 'like', 'like', 'comment', 'like', 'like', 'share', 'like', 'comment', 'like', 'share', 'like')

dat <- data.frame(from, to, interaction_type)
```

which, if aggregate correctly, should find the most common type of interaction between any unique pairs (regardless of directionality (i.e., A-->B, A<--B)) like this

```
from    to  type
A       B   like
A       C   like
A       D   share
B       C   like
B       D   comment
C       D   like
```

While it's easy to get the total count of interaction between any two users by using

```
count <- ddply(sub_test, .(from, to), nrow)
```

I found it hard to apply similar method to find the most common type of interaction between any given pairs with this aggregation method. What will be the most efficient way to achieve my desired output? Also, how to handle possible "tied" cases? (I might just use "tided" as the cell values for all tied cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Ronak's approach

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(from, to, interaction_type, stringsAsFactors = F)
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    pair = purrr::pmap_chr(
      .l = list(from = from, to = to),
      .f = function(from, to) paste(sort(c(from, to)), collapse = "")
    )
  ) %>%
  group_by(pair) %>%
  filter(n() == max(n()) & row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-pair)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  from  to    interaction_type
  <chr> <chr> <chr>           
1 A     B     like            
2 A     D     share           
3 B     C     like            
4 B     D     comment         
5 C     A     like            
6 C     D     like
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is a very efficient method to obtain the desired max values in the third column.

Answer (score 2):

We need to find the most common value (mode) per group irrespective of order of columns `from`, `to`.

Taking the `Mode` function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914) answer

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

We can use `dplyr` to get first appearing maximum value for the group.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(key = paste0(pmin(from, to), pmax(from, to), sep = "")) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(interaction_type = Mode(interaction_type)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-key)

#  from  to    interaction_type
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>           
#1 A     B     like            
#2 C     A     like            
#3 A     D     share           
#4 B     C     like            
#5 B     D     comment         
#6 C     D     like
```

Kept columns as characters by adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your data.

Comment: Thanks for the `stringsAsFactors` tip!