# R: how to create ID variable for unordered pairs in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing variables on trade flows between pairs of countries, one country being the exporter and one being the importer for each row.

I want to create an ID number variable which identifies each *unordered* country pair, giving the same ID number to each pair regardless of which is the exporter and which is the importer. So Australia-United States would have the same ID as United States-Australia but a different ID to Australia-Great Britain.

This is an example of what the data with the ID variable would look like.

```
YEAR     ISO_EXP     ISO_IMP     UNORD_PAIR_ID
1970     AUS         GBR         1
1970     AUS         USA         2
1970     AUS         ZIM         3
1970     GBR         AUS         1
1970     GBR         USA         4
1970     GBR         ZIM         5
1970     USA         AUS         2
1970     USA         GBR         4
1970     USA         ZIM         6
1970     ZIM         AUS         3
1970     ZIM         GBR         5
1970     ZIM         USA         6
```

My dataset has around 2 million rows, comprising around 44,000 country pairs over 47 years.

I have used the following code to create an ID for each *ordered* country pair.

```
data$ORD_PAIR_ID <- data %>% group_indices(data$ISO_EXP, data$ISO_IMP)
```

But I have not been able to work out how to create an ID for *unordered* pairs.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145982/data-table-with-two-string-columns-of-set-elements-extract-unique-rows-with-eac/25151395 or here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297812/pair-wise-duplicate-removal-from-dataframe and check out the questions linked from those in-turn. Or even this one early today which covered a similar problem in dplyr - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733670/combining-data-frame-based-on-data-in-each-column-in-dplyr/55734428

Comment: Btw, doing `data %>% group_indices(data$ISO_EXP, data$ISO_IMP)` is going to break your analyses pretty quickly. You want to do `data %>% group_indices(ISO_EXP, ISO_IMP)` - no need to subset via `$` as you are working within `data` via the `%>%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can sort the elements in the same of ISO_EXP, ISO_IMP with `pmin/pmax` and use that in `group_indices`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%  
    mutate(pairid = group_indices(., pmax(ISO_EXP, ISO_IMP), 
                                     pmin(ISO_EXP, ISO_IMP)))
#   YEAR ISO_EXP ISO_IMP UNORD_PAIR_ID pairid
#1  1970     AUS     GBR             1      1
#2  1970     AUS     USA             2      2
#3  1970     AUS     ZIM             3      4
#4  1970     GBR     AUS             1      1
#5  1970     GBR     USA             4      3
#6  1970     GBR     ZIM             5      5
#7  1970     USA     AUS             2      2
#8  1970     USA     GBR             4      3
#9  1970     USA     ZIM             6      6
#10 1970     ZIM     AUS             3      4
#11 1970     ZIM     GBR             5      5
#12 1970     ZIM     USA             6      6
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, as.data.frame(t(apply(df1[2:3], 1, sort))))
df1$pairid <-  match(v1, unique(v1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(YEAR = c(1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 
 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L, 1970L), ISO_EXP = c("AUS", 
  "AUS", "AUS", "GBR", "GBR", "GBR", "USA", "USA", "USA", "ZIM", 
  "ZIM", "ZIM"), ISO_IMP = c("GBR", "USA", "ZIM", "AUS", "USA", 
  "ZIM", "AUS", "GBR", "ZIM", "AUS", "GBR", "USA"), UNORD_PAIR_ID = c(1L, 
  2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thanks v. much akrun. This has achieved what I wanted.

Comment: I found the base R solution worked. I upvoted your answer, but as a new use of stackoverflow I do not have enough reputation points for my vote to display.Thanks again.